# jquery through inputs and add them

Tags: jquery, forms, input, each

I had a ton of help from someone to create a jquery code snippet to auto-calculate form inputs based on tax rates. Now i'm trying to figure out how to cycle through each input, add them together and then output them in specific table td's.

I took a crack at adding the sub_total, tax one total, and tax two total and sales tax total but it didn't work. I'd also like for each row's total to the right. I haven't got the slightest idea about how to go about doing that.

heres the jsfiddle that i'm working on. http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/20/

perfected --> http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/39/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. I've rewriten your code partially. Maybe it will be useful for you:

**Code: http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/28/**

Main calculation here:

```
function CalculateData()
{
    var price = parseFloat($(this).val());

    var tax_one_rate = parseFloat($('[name="tax_one_rate"]').val()),
        tax_two_rate = parseFloat($('[name="tax_two_rate"]').val()),
        sales_tax_rate = parseFloat($('[name="sales_tax_rate"]').val());

    var $tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    $tr.find('td input[name="tax_one[]"]').val((tax_one_rate * 0.01 * price).toFixed(2));
    $tr.find('td input[name="tax_two[]"]').val((tax_two_rate * 0.01 * price).toFixed(2));
    $tr.find('td input[name="sales_tax[]"]').val((sales_tax_rate * 0.01 * price).toFixed(2));

    var rowTotal = 0;
    $tr.find('td:gt(1) input').each(function() {
        rowTotal += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $tr.find('#row_total').text((price - rowTotal).toFixed(2));

    CalculateTotal();
}
```

Comment: wow. this is awesome. The only thing that i don't know about is the live() function isn't being used. Rows will be added dynamically vai jquery and when we didn't use live() the new rows weren't being affected. Also, how could i bind the calculations to tax_one[], tax_two[], and sales_tax[] along with price[] and not the tax rates?

Comment: Fill free to change direct event binding to `live`.

Comment: About the second question you need to mark somehow manually changed field (ex. via attribute) and then exclude such fields from autcalculation and only gen value from them

Comment: could you explain what this is doing? --> find('td:gt(1) input')

Comment: Here mistake: should be `find('td:gt(0) input')` - it means that first `td` element will be skipped. `gt` is greater then.

Comment: I modified your previous one to suit my project a little better but i broke it. I added a function thats sole purpose is to calculate the rows total. I prefer not to use the gt(0) input because i may add hidden fields that don't need to be calculated. Could look over it and see whats going wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/35/

Comment: updated working better, i can't get the CalculateRow to trigger when the price[] is changed though. I think i need to be using the trigger() function somehow. I don't want each() being used. I want it to be calculated on a row by row basis, not a blanket recalculation

Answer (score 3):

You're using **this** to refer to the current input field,inside your each loops, when you should use **$(this)**.

Also, you should parse all input values to float, in your current fiddle you're just joining strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/xvsC7/3/

Comment: thanks for the response. I fixed that but it still doesn't seem to be working http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/23/

Comment: this is great, thanks! do you know how to search for the next instance of "#row_total" and update that td?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `.toFixed` method on a String (3x addition of `.val()`). Convert these strings to a number. Also, you've forgotten to use `.val()` on your last input element, at `var row_total = ..`

```
var row_total = (parseInt($inputs.eq(1).val(), 10)
               + parseInt($inputs.eq(2).val(), 10)
               + parseInt($inputs.eq(3).val(), 10)).toFixed(2);
```

Finally, replace all occurrences of `this.val()` by `this.value` (*or `$(this).val()`*).

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SU5jU/26/**

Comment: awesome, thanks for that! you wouldn't happen to know how to only update the #row_total for the specific row would you?

Comment: IDs should be unique. Use `class="row_total"`, for example, and use `$(this).parent().next('.row_total')`.